# Excel VBA: Need to Delete Rows in which Cells contain a Date within 7 days of the current Date

Tags: excel, vba

I have tried this with using a r1c1 formula and autofilter.  I have also tried piecing together code I've found on the internet, but nothing is working properly.  I am very much an amateur looking for help, please.

I need the code to look in a specific column and delete all rows in which cells in that column are within 7 days of today's date.  So today's date 12/5/2017, I need to delete all rows containing dates 11/28 through 12/5.

This must always evaluate based on current date.  Any help is so greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Sub DeleteLastContact()

Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range, compRng As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
Set compRng = ws.UsedRange.Columns("AE")

Dim delRng As Range, tmpVal As Date

For Each cel In compRng.Cells
Debug.Print cel.value
    tmpVal = cel.value
    If tmpVal < Date - 7 Then
        If delRng Is Nothing Then
            Set delRng = cel
        Else
            Set delRng = Union(cel, delRng)
        End If
    End If
Next cel

If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete



End Sub
```

Comment: Help us to help you; **post your current code.**

Comment: show what you have done so far.

Comment: Put the code in the original post using [edit] so it can be formatted.

Comment: Apologies.  This is my first post, I forgot to add the code in the correct format.  All set now

Comment: In VBE, press `Ctrl + G`. Are all the values in the window (from your `Debug.Print Cel.Value` line) dates? If not, that would be why you are receiving this error. And I thought you changed `Sheet1` to `Data`?

Comment: Sorry I did change back to sheet "Data" in the code.  Pressing ctrl + G I receive the header in column AE -  Last_Contact_Date

Comment: I edited the UsedRange line to read                                                           
    `Set compRng = ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Columns("AE")                        
                                                                                                                       
It works beautifully now!  Thank you so much @K.Davis

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, let me know if you have errors.

You can iterate through all cells in column AE, add each cell that meets your criteria to a special range, then at the end delete all rows in your special range.

```
Sub DeleteLastContact()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, cel As Range, compRng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set compRng = ws.UsedRange.Columns("AE")

    Dim delRng As Range, tmpVal As Date

    For Each cel In compRng.Cells
        tmpVal = cel.Value
        If tmpVal < Date - 7 Then
            If delRng Is Nothing Then
                Set delRng = cel
            Else
                Set delRng = Union(cel, delRng)
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

    If Not delRng Is Nothing Then delRng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  I receive a Run-time error '13':  Type mismatch for the line:  
    tmpVal = cel.value

Comment: I updated code shortly after I posted it. You may have seen the old code. I changed the For...Each statement portion of `compRng` to `compRng.Cells`. See if that helps

Comment: Thanks again for the help.  But I am receiving the same error. I will continue to try and work with what you have given me, thanks.

Comment: @John then there may be some cells in the range that are errors like `#value` or `#N/A`.  You may need to test for errors first.

Comment: Are all the columns in use prior to **AE**? If not, that can mess with the `UsedRange` method. And can you verify that only dates appear in **Column AE**? Also, verify the worksheet is actually `Sheet1` you are trying to run this on. Also, a header in `AE1` that is not a date may be to blame

Comment: @K.Davis.  All the columns prior to AE are in use. The name of my sheet is "Data", so I changed sheet1 to Data.  There are only Dates and blank cells in column AE.

Comment: right below the `For...Each` statement, add this line `Debug.Print Cel.Value` and see if what you are seeing are dates in the immediate window.

Comment: I have edited the original code above to reflect the changes.  Still receiving the same error on the same line.